# Section Content overlapping Header when scrolled

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a web page and I'm facing this issue, I have a nav bar which is fixed and working fine. I have two sections for now and when scrolled first section works fine but other one is overlapping the Nav which I'll show it to you via JSFiddle.

What I have tried so far is that to make the **.items** display as block but didn't get the solution. 
Tried using position as absolute but it affected my view. So for now everything is working fine except this one that the section 2 which **testimonial-one** is overlapping the header the first section is working fine.

I have also tried using this **nav-fixed-top** in my bootstrap nav but it didn't work out.

```css
.navbar { padding: 26px !important; position: fixed!important; width: 100%}
.navbar a img {width: auto; height: 45px}
body{ padding-top: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.home-page {background-image: url("assets/images/home_image.jpg"); background-size: cover; padding-bottom: 125px; padding-top: 0; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.home-page H1 {font-family: "HelveticaNeueThin"; padding-top: 219px; font-size: 52px!important; color: #616161}

.testimonial-one {padding: 0}
.testimonial-one .content-offset {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.testimonial-one {padding: 0}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- jQuery Script -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Just an image -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home" style="border-bottom: none">
          <img src="img" alt="TESTING">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="pt-lg-0 pt-3 collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-1">HELLO</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">WORLD</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">HOW</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">ARE</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">YOU</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">FINE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="home-page" id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Bringing ease to<br>each home</h1>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 400px"></div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="testimonial-one container" id="page-1">
      <div class="content-offset">
        <img src="assets/images/left.png" alt='' class="prev"/>
        <img src="assets/images/right.png" alt='' class="next"/>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="items">
          <div><p style="font-size:80px">Hello</p></div>
            <div><p style="font-size:80px">Hello</p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my JSFiddle link, kindly help me. Thanks. Link : [JSFiddle Work](https://jsfiddle.net/hg4q2vvz/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a `z-index` to your navbar. This will place the navbar on a "higher layer" than the rest of the content.

```css
.navbar { padding: 26px !important; position: fixed!important; width: 100%; z-index: 10;}
.navbar a img {width: auto; height: 45px}
body{ padding-top: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.home-page {background-image: url("assets/images/home_image.jpg"); background-size: cover; padding-bottom: 125px; padding-top: 0; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.home-page H1 {font-family: "HelveticaNeueThin"; padding-top: 219px; font-size: 52px!important; color: #616161}

.testimonial-one {padding: 0}
.testimonial-one .content-offset {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.testimonial-one {padding: 0}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- jQuery Script -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Just an image -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home" style="border-bottom: none">
          <img src="img" alt="TESTING">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="pt-lg-0 pt-3 collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#page-1">HELLO</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">WORLD</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">HOW</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">ARE</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">YOU</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">FINE</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="home-page" id="home">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Bringing ease to<br>each home</h1>
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block" style="margin-top: 400px"></div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="testimonial-one container" id="page-1">
      <div class="content-offset">
        <img src="assets/images/left.png" alt='' class="prev"/>
        <img src="assets/images/right.png" alt='' class="next"/>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="items">
          <div><p style="font-size:80px">Hello</p></div>
            <div><p style="font-size:80px">Hello</p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Briiliant! Thanks. However z-index: 1 also does the work. I don't find any difference there. Could you please tell me what happens when we use higher z-index? Thanks

Comment: There is no difference in this case. However, it is useful when you are stacking multiple layers. `z-index` only has an effect on relative, fixed, or absolute positioned elements. Then, z-index indicates the 'layer' the element is on, where a higher number is more on top. See this example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0yum10zp/3/